# Precise Definition of a Group Parameterization

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

I've ran across the term "parameterization" used in group theory, especially for Lie groups, but I've never seen group parameterization precisely defined.

From the context I usually find it in, it seems like a parameterization of a group $G$ is a mapping from a subset of a field to a representation of the group, where the subset is often defined by some finite number of constraints. For example, $SU(2)$ is parameterized by the subset of the field of quarternions obeying $qq^* = 1.$ It should be the case that $SO(3)$ can be parameterized by the same set, even though the mapping is only surjective in this case. Perhaps the latter is really an "inherited" parameterization since $SU(2)$ is the universal cover of $SO(3)$?

Does anybody know of a precise definition of group parameterization?

Comment: Do you know the definition of a differentiable manifold? If you do, the notion of a (local) parameterization (in math) is the same for Lie groups as for general manifolds. At the same time, the notion of a parameterization used in physics is very inconsistent. I suggest you add specific references (to the instances where the word "parameterization" is used) in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the comment--I assume that a local parameterization of a differentiable manifold is the same as a choice of coordinate chart? In this case, I'm not sure that's the same idea of parameterization, since it seems to me that a "group parameterization" should be global. I've seen it in many sources--not all physics--I was just wondering if there was a standard definition I missed.

Comment: That's right, it is the same as the local parameterization. There is no consistency in the terminology, which is not that surprising as it is going back to the 19th century. Most mathematicians require parameterizations to be local diffeomorphisms and defined on open subsets in $R^n$. With this interpretation, most compact Lie groups (e.g. $SU(2)$) do not admit a useful global parameterization. As I suggested, you should include your sources, to make this question answerable.

Comment: OK--I'll try to find a few sources to improve the question. The only difficulty is that it's been a recurring question for me while reading many, many books and papers, and I don't want to miss any important ones. I think the answer is probably just like you say: there's no single standard definition, but a given author might have a particular thing they're thinking about when they use the term.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tentative answer:

1. Mathematicians prefer not to think in terms of a parameterization (of Lie groups), but work instead with an atlas of charts, making **parameterizations** local. Among the charts, the most important one is at $e\in G$ and the standard chart at $e$ is given by the exponential map (although the choice of a  domain and codomain is ambiguous).
2. For Lie groups, as for general manifolds, there are other notions of "parameterizations" used in the literature. The only commonality between these notions is that a parameterization is required to be a smooth map whose image in $G$ has nonempty interior and contain $e$. Domains of such maps are sometimes allowed to be other manifolds, sometimes are required to be open subsets in ${\mathbb R}^n$. The maps themselves are sometimes required to be local diffeomorphisms, sometimes not.  Sometimes parameterizations are required to be injective/surjective, sometimes not.
3. The definition of a parameterization given in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametrization_(geometry)) is OK as a non-technical explanation, but is lacking mathematical rigor. In contrast, the linked OSU page is essentially an explanation of an atlas of charts for non-experts.